# How to pass dynamic data to the multiple markers in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, marker

I want to pass some dynamic data to the markers which I am creating in a loop.

Finally when I click on any marker it is displaying last added marker data only.

```
var i=0
//creating multilple markers
while(coordinates.Latitude[i]){
           marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(coordinates.Latitude[i], 
                           coordinates.Longitude[i]),{icon: greenIcon});
           //adding data to the marker
           marker.myData = { id: coordinates.Latitude[i] };
           marker.on('click', function (e) {
                    alert(marker.myData.id);
           });
           map.addLayer(marker);
           i++;
  }
```

I want each and every marker should have their own data(i,e lattitude).

Comment: Can you share your `coordinates` object so that I can replicate it?

Comment: const coordinates={"Latitude":{"0":17.7222014,"1":17.3924217,"2":17.3906471,"3":17.433709},"Longitude":{"0":83.2892612,"1":78.4689988,"2":78.5009093,"3":78.5016144}}

Comment: Another instance of the classic problem of not being careful about scopes of variables. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this code?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
      }

      #map {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    const coordinates = {
      Latitude: {
        '0': 17.7222014,
        '1': 17.3924217,
        '2': 17.3906471,
        '3': 17.433709,
      },
      Longitude: {
        '0': 83.2892612,
        '1': 78.4689988,
        '2': 78.5009093,
        '3': 78.5016144,
      },
    };

    const map = L.map('map').setView([17.3924217, 78.4689988], 7);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    }).addTo(map);

    for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(coordinates.Latitude).length; i += 1) {
      const marker = L.marker([
        coordinates.Latitude[i.toString()],
        coordinates.Longitude[i.toString()],
      ]);
      marker.myData = { id: coordinates.Latitude[i.toString()] };

      marker.on('click', function(e) {
        alert(marker.myData.id);
      });

      marker.addTo(map);
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: If it was helpful, can you please accept this answer?